# How to send location data to Firestore Database when app is killed in FLUTTER

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, background-process, flutter-dependencies

I have been trying to create an app in flutter which sends the location data of a user to the Firestore Database EVEN WHEN THE APP IS KILLED.

This plugin works well to get the location data when the app is killed:
https://github.com/rekab-app/background_locator

The problem is that I am unable to update the Firestore Database values in the 'callback' function of this plugin

Here is my code:

```
static void callback(LocationDto locationDto) async {
    print('location in dart: ${locationDto.toString()}');
    final SendPort send = IsolateNameServer.lookupPortByName(_isolateName);
    send?.send(locationDto);
    await DatabaseService(uid:UID).updateUserLocation(
            (locationDto.latitude).toString(),
            (locationDto.longitude).toString());

  }
```

The DatabaseService.updateUserLocation method is:

```
 Future updateUserLocation(String latitude,String longitude) async
  {
    return await location_collection.document(uid).setData({
      'Longitude':longitude,
      'Latitude':latitude
    });
  }
```

The error is in sending the locationDto to the FireStore Database
The exact error is:

```
[ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(157)] Unhandled Exception: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method DocumentReference#setData on channel plugins.flutter.io/cloud_firestore)
```

This relates to the setData() function in the updateUserLocation method.

How do I send the location data of the user to my Firestore Database EVEN WHEN THE APP IS KILLED?

It would be great if someone could help me on this!!!

Thanks!

Comment: Use Firebase Cloud Messaging to send a push notification to your app.  You app will be launched in order to receive the message.

Comment: The app is for van drivers so they might not open the app when the notification arrives. Could you suggest a way of sending the users location to Firestore when the app is killed. Thanks!

Comment: @ManasBam did you find any solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same situation with shared_preferences, when get token. So, I think in create a new instance inside callback method, and works. I mean, try to call location_collection inside callback method like new object.

And added this in Application app

```
override fun registerWith(registry: PluginRegistry?) {
       if (!registry!!.hasPlugin("io.flutter.plugins.sharedpreferences")) {
            SharedPreferencesPlugin.registerWith(registry!!.registrarFor("io.flutter.plugins.sharedpreferences"))
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

To use Firestore you should add those lines to your Application.kt.

```
import io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication
import io.flutter.plugin.common.PluginRegistry
import io.flutter.plugin.common.PluginRegistry.PluginRegistrantCallback
import io.flutter.plugins.pathprovider.PathProviderPlugin
// Add this line
import io.flutter.plugins.firebase.cloudfirestore.CloudFirestorePlugin;
import io.flutter.view.FlutterMain
import rekab.app.background_locator.LocatorService

class Application : FlutterApplication(), PluginRegistrantCallback {
    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        LocatorService.setPluginRegistrant(this)
        FlutterMain.startInitialization(this)
    }

    override fun registerWith(registry: PluginRegistry?) {
        if (!registry!!.hasPlugin("io.flutter.plugins.pathprovider")) {
            PathProviderPlugin.registerWith(registry!!.registrarFor("io.flutter.plugins.pathprovider"))
        }
// Add this section
        if (!registry!!.hasPlugin("io.flutter.plugins.firebase.firestore")) {
CloudFirestorePlugin.registerWith(registry!!.registrarFor("io.flutter.plugins.firebase.firestore"))
        }
        
    }
}
```

It worked for me. Let me know if it works for you too.